# Angular 2 - how to determine when a view is fully resolved

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular 2 and trying to determine when a view (in a component) is fully loaded (bindings completed) within an Angular view - when fully loaded I then need to run a script (to generate a PDF from the view).

I've looked at the Angular hooks - the only one, it seems, that can really be leveraged is ngAfterViewChecked however this is called for each each corresponding change - I need to know when all changes to the view have been applied to the view (i.e. upon/after the last ngAfterViewChecked call) - but how is this known ?

Comment: Your question needs more detail about what you're trying to accomplish and why along with code samples of what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is also the AfterViewInit lifecycle hook, which is called once the component is fully initialized.

```
export class AfterViewComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log('AfterViewInit');
    this.doSomething();
  }

  // ...
}
```

See also https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#afterview

**Edit 1:**

You are right, the value isn't set in the beginning. As far as I know there is no other lifecycle hook after the AfterViewInit (which is called only once). You can though use the setTimeout method with 0 seconds delay. This will basically push the method call to the end of the current execution queue and give angular the time to update the databindings.

```
export class AfterViewComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout( () => {
        this.doSomething();
    },0)
  }

  // ...
}
```

Example on Plunkr to illustrate the result: https://plnkr.co/edit/s5DDTtiaVw73QBoYuv4z

**Edit 2:**

As mentioned by bryan60 in the comments, the lifecycle hook has no way to know when a server event is happening. You would handle this in your code.

Plunkr example: https://plnkr.co/edit/ZgPcl2qLEom03ZClAutT?p=preview

When the data is coming from the server, you assign it to your local variable(s). If you would immediately invoke your printPdf() method, the databindings wouldn't be updated, as angular didn't yet have the time to check for any changes. So instead of directly invoking the printPdf() method, you use the setTimeout trick to let angular update the databindings first.

```
ngOnInit() {
    // This would be your HTTP method to load the data from the server
    this.loadData().subscribe((data) => {
        this.data = data;      

        setTimeout(() => {
            this.printPdf();
        }, 0)
    });
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately AfterViewInit fires before the element is actually hydrated with the bound value

Comment: @TerrorBight I updated my answer. Can you check if it is working for you?

Comment: ngAfterViewChecked (called mult. times) occurs *after* ngAfterViewInit - as far as I can see, the code above doesn't do anything to the order of the events.  With regards to the "this.before", I'm unclear what your intent is - if an exception occurs are you suggesting it to be ignored

Comment: By using setTimeout, the doSomething() method will be delayed by one tick. In that timeframe, the databindings of the component will be updated when calling the doSomething() method.

By no means I meant that the error should be ignored. I wanted to point out that you should not assign a value during that timeframe without using the setTimeout method, as otherwise there will be this error. In the Plunkr example I left it in simply to showcase that using setTimeout does use the updated values.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but the one tick isn't enough time for a long list of fields that need binding - there's no change in my application to indicate there is a change in behavior with/without the setTimeout - I could easily set the timeout to be higher but I need to know everything is guaranteed to be resolved and no time is wasted waiting

Comment: Can you maybe elaborate more on your case? A long list of fields should be no problem at all, as angular will update all databindings. The method within setTimeout should then be called after all databindings were updated. Is the data of your view coming in asynchronously?

Comment: Aftercontentinit is the last cycle in the hook. But define the term “resolve” what are you talking about?? Data fetched from a server?

Comment: Within the component, I'm calling a server-side service (using http.get) OnInit which is the data that gets is bound to the view - if I break-point within ngAfterViewInit, the view doesn't contain the data however if I break-point within ngAfterViewChecked when going through the many calls (as it is called for each change), I see the view being updated with the data field by field.

Comment: Aftercontentinit is midway thru the life-cycle https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks - by 'resolve' I mean the view is fully populated with the bound data

Comment: Ah I see, if the data is coming in asynchronously, you have to use the setTimeout where the data is coming in. Assuming you use an observable:
this.loadData.subscribe( () => { setTimeout( () => {this.createPdf }, 0) }. I will update my answer in a few minutes.

Comment: There is no way to use lifecycle hooks to tell when server data is received, nor is there a way to use timeouts.  You need to use the resolve feature of the router.

Comment: That seems to work - I know you've spent more than enough time on this, which I greatly appreciate, but is there an explanation of why this works - and is it something that can be relied on to work across browsers/devices

Comment: @TerrorBight At the time you are setting the data in your subscription, angular will not have updated your view. It will do so after all methods of your subscription have been executed. The setTimeout will also be executed immediately, but the method you are calling inside the setTimeout will be pushed at the end of the current javascript execution queue. In that way we can ensure that the updating of the view was done before calling the method inside the setTimeout. I assume that this should be reliable on all browser and devices which support setTimeout, but I only ever used it with Chrome.

Comment: Many thanks for the explanation @Kergoss - it makes sense - the solution works well